# What does it mean when constant local variables are stored in the assembly data region, while non-constant local variables are stored on the stack?

Tags: c#, constants, local-variables

I'm reading through this [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Variables) and don't understand what this means within the local variables section? An ELI5 would be helpful <3

Comment: Constant local variable are public variables that are not inside methods(functions or subroutines).  So they are put into a table called "assembly data region".  Variables inside methods are put on the execution stack.  When a method is called the compiles reserves memory on the execution stack which is the size of the total of all the variables required to execute the method.  So if a method declares int a;int b; int c;  An integer is 4 bytes so 4 x 3 = 12 bytes are reserved on the stack for the local variables.

Comment: @jdweng - constant *local* variables *are* declared inside methods. That's what makes them local.

Comment: @jdweng - And "variables that are not inside methods" go on the Heap, not in a data region. That's about 'variable' vs 'constant'.

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact - the stack is an implementation detail that is mostly irrelevant. Most references to `stack` within the C# Spec are to a toy `Stack<T>` class than references to a/the execution stack.

Let's take a toy method:

```
public int Compute(int value)
{
   int b = value/2;
   if (b > 10){
      return b + Compute(b);
   }
   return b - 4;
}
```

This `Compute` method needs *somewhere* where it can store the contents of the `b` variable. Importantly, this method may *recurse*<sup>1</sup>, that is, it may call *itself*, possibly repeatedly, and it's important that each execution of the method retains its own copy of the `b` variable. If there was just a single storage space for the `b` variable in memory, then recursion wouldn't be possible.<sup>2</sup>

So, the storage for variables has to be dynamically provided - each time a method is entered, new storage has to be made available for the local variables. And one particularly common way to provide such storage is via a "stack frame" or "activation record". *How much* storage is actually required is subject to a complex discussion involving optimization and variable lifetimes, but in the trivial case we say that the stack frame contains enough storage space for each local variable.

However, `const` locals are special variables - because they *don't* vary. As an optimization, then, we *can* just store one copy of this variable somewhere, and every instance of `Compute` that is running can just reference that single copy.

---

<sup>1</sup>Here, it's trivially recursive, but it need not be so - the recursion could be hidden through a number of intermediate method calls to other methods.

<sup>2</sup>Nor could we allow the method to be called by multiple threads.